# How to decompress lzo byte array using java-lzo library?

Tags: java, maven, lzo

I'm trying to decompress compressed byte array using java-lzo library. I'm following [**this reference**](https://github.com/shevek/lzo-java).

I added below **maven dependency** to pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.anarres.lzo</groupId>
        <artifactId>lzo-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I created one method which accepts lzo compressed byte array and destination byte array length as a argument.

**Program :**

```
private byte[] decompress(byte[] src, int len) {
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(src);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    LzoAlgorithm algorithm = LzoAlgorithm.LZO1X;
    lzo_uintp lzo = new lzo_uintp(len);
    LzoDecompressor decompressor = LzoLibrary.getInstance().newDecompressor(algorithm, null);
    LzoInputStream stream = new LzoInputStream(input, decompressor);

    try {
        int data = stream.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            out.write(data);
            data = stream.read();
        }
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

I got stuck at one point because **stream.read() always returns a "-1"**. I checked input array it is filled with data. Further I checked using stream.available() method but this method also returns always "0" in my case. But If I checked to InputStream like input.available() then the return value is length of array.

Error is same just like I said it is returning "-1" -

```
java.io.EOFException
at org.anarres.lzo.LzoInputStream.readBytes(LzoInputStream.java:183)
at org.anarres.lzo.LzoInputStream.readBlock(LzoInputStream.java:132)
at org.anarres.lzo.LzoInputStream.fill(LzoInputStream.java:119)
at org.anarres.lzo.LzoInputStream.read(LzoInputStream.java:90)
```

So, while initializing LzoInputStream I'm wrong or after that I need to do something? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the compression method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that lzo stream are are flushed and closed during compression.

Comment: I'm not compressing this data. Data is coming from the network. I can definitely say It is flushed and closed while compressing.

Answer (score 0):

For a `.lzo` file format, you should first read the header information and then pass it on to the `LzoInputStream`.
Then you can read the actual data till you reach eof.

I guess first 37 bytes are header related info and the compression algorithm information is available in 16th byte.
LZO header format is documented at https://gist.github.com/jledet/1333896